# ConfusionMatrix erroneous output R for Decision Tree

Tags: r, decision-tree

Hi I'm training a decision tree model using R. When trying to interpret the confusion matrix I'm getting the following error.

```
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
```

#######################Decision Tree#####################

```
set.seed(3033)
intrain <- createDataPartition(y = new_columns$yyes, p= 0.7, list = FALSE)
training <- new_columns[intrain,]
testing <- new_columns[-intrain,]

#check dimensions of train & test set
dim(training); 
dim(testing);

trctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 3)


set.seed(3333)
dtree_fit <- train(yyes ~., data = training, method = "rpart",
                   parms = list(split = "information"),
                   trControl=trctrl,
                   tuneLength = 10)
dtree_fit

prp(dtree_fit$finalModel, box.palette = "Reds", tweak = 1.2)

testing[1,]
predict(dtree_fit, newdata = testing[1,])

test_pred <- predict(dtree_fit, newdata = testing)
confusionMatrix(test_pred, testing$yyes )  #check accuracy
```

My test_pred value gives results like below,

[image]

testing$yyes

[image]

So I think the issue is with, binaries and decimals. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a classification task, but are it looks like you are fitting a regression tree which is why you get decimals in `test_pred`. Further, `confusionMatrix()` literally wants factors.

You can solve both issues by coercing `yyes` to a factor before fitting your model. That should clue `rpart` in that you want a classification tree and then your predictions will be factors with the same levels.

Here's a reproducible example.

```
# Notice the coercion happens before doing anything else.
.iris <- iris %>% mutate(group = as.factor(group))
train = .iris[1:100,]
test = .iris[101:150,]

tree_fit <- train(group ~ . , data = train, method = 'rpart') 
test_pred <- predict(tree_fit, test)
confusionMatrix(test_pred, test$group)
```

Comment: Can you kindly provide me a small example

Comment: I'm getting the same error :( Following is the change I did.
# Notice the coercion happens before doing anything else.
.new_columns <- new_columns %>% mutate(yyes = as.factor(yyes))

But still having the same issue.

Comment: Maybe you can make a reproducible example.